# Storing rendering data for voxel game 1 VAO and VBO or 1 for every chunk

Tags: opengl, voxels, vbo, transparency, vao

I have a minecraft style voxel game with placing and digging blocks. it runs at 400+ fps on my computer but when I added semi-transparent water it started running at ~40 fps. so a time per frame increase of 0.0175s or 8 times what is used to be. What I am currently doing is having a VAO and VBO for each chunk and every time a chunk is changed or loaded it finds all of the non occluded blocks and puts their positions into another buffer in the chunk. then I use instancing to render the whole chunk in one draw call so every frame I am doing ~300 draw calls.

Once I added the water(using order independent transparency http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/08/20/is-order-independent-transparency-really-necessary/) I was individually calling gldrawelements() for every visible water block so around 9000 if half the visible area is ocean. I know using instancing with these blocks would help but then I have 2 VAOs for every chunk and 600+ draw calls of buffers with only a couple hundred blocks in them. would there be a better way to organize these things.

Comment: I think its the OIT that is killing your frames. I use a reflection buffer and refraction buffer for my water shader then draw it opaque and do some shader math  to blend the two buffers.... refraction buffer is just the last frames backbuffer. Ill write an answer if you want?

Comment: @Justin William Stanley Bryant whats an OIT? and I've never heard of reflection or refraction buffers. An answer would be realy helpful

Comment: OIT = order independent transparency, will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1):

I base my water shader off of [this work](https://habibs.wordpress.com/lake/), its directX based but I'm sure with a bit of work you can convert it over but ill go over how I do it so you have an idea\recipe.

First up I make a copy of the current frames back buffer to use as the refraction buffer or you can draw everything again and use clip planes but I only do that for the reflection buffer to save a heap of draw calls at the cost of some artifacts in the refraction buffer.

I then compute a reflection camera and then draw everything that I want to reflect into the reflection buffer using the reflection camera as the view matrix.

Water Camera View:

```
    // play with the (0,0,0) value here to adjust the water camera offset
    Dim WaterPos As Vector3 = BasePos + CType(Vector3.Transform(New Vector3(0, 0, 0), Matrix.RotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(0)) * Matrix.RotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(_yaw))), Vector3)  

    WaterPos.Y = -WaterPos.Y + 175 * 2 // sets the camera Y cord(adjust 175 to water height +- 3-5)

    //locks the pitch part of the rotation matrix 
    Dim watertemp As Matrix = Matrix.RotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(15)) * Matrix.RotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(_yaw)) * Matrix.Translation(WaterPos)
```

I have the reflection buffer resolution set to 1/4 full screen resolution make sure it has the same aspect as the back buffer it the projection will fail, the normal perturbation(waves+wind) hides the jaggyness.

When I come to render the water I just draw the water plain with an opaque blendstate and use this shader to blend it all togeather.

Water shader:

```
WaterVertexToPixel WaterVS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float2 inTex: TEXCOORD)

{

WaterVertexToPixel Output = (WaterVertexToPixel)0;

float4×4 preViewProjection = mul (xView, xProjection);

float4×4 preWorldViewProjection = mul (xWorld, preViewProjection);

float4×4 preReflectionViewProjection = mul (xReflectionView, xProjection);

float4×4 preWorldReflectionViewProjection = mul (xWorld, preReflectionViewProjection);

Output.Position = mul(inPos, preWorldViewProjection);
Output.ReflectionMapSamplingPos = mul(inPos, preWorldReflectionViewProjection);

Output.RefractionMapSamplingPos = mul(inPos, preWorldViewProjection);

return Output;

}

void WaterPS(WaterVertexToPixel PSIn)

{

    float3 eyeVector = normalize(WorldCameraPos - WorldPos);

float3 NormalData1 = 0;
float3 NormalData2 = 0;

NormalData1 = BumpMap1.Sample(samANISOTROPIC,texturecoords).rgb;
NormalData2 = BumpMap2.Sample(samANISOTROPIC, texturecoords).rgb;

float3 normalT = normalize(lerp(NormalData1 - 0.5, NormalData2 - 0.5, flowLerp) *2);
  float2 perturbation = WaveHeight * normalT.rg;

// Project Reflection Buffer To Water Surface
ProjectedTexCoords.x = PSIn.ReflectionMapSamplingPos.x/PSIn.ReflectionMapSamplingPos.w/2.0f + 0.5f;

ProjectedTexCoords.y =   PSIn.ReflectionMapSamplingPos.y/PSIn.ReflectionMapSamplingPos.w/2.0f + 0.5f;
float2 perturbatedTexCoords = ProjectedTexCoords + perturbation;
float4 reflectiveColor = tex2D(ReflectionSampler, perturbatedTexCoords);

 // Project Refraction Buffer To Water Surface
ProjectedRefrTexCoords.x = PSIn.RefractionMapSamplingPos.x/PSIn.RefractionMapSamplingPos.w/2.0f + 0.5f;

ProjectedRefrTexCoords.y = -PSIn.RefractionMapSamplingPos.y/PSIn.RefractionMapSamplingPos.w/2.0f + 0.5f;
    float2 perturbatedRefrTexCoords = ProjectedRefrTexCoords + perturbation;
float4 refractiveColor = tex2D(RefractionSampler, perturbatedRefrTexCoords);


float3 combinedColor;  

//The Fresnel equations, deduced by Augustin-Jean Fresnel, describe the behaviour of light when moving between media of differing refractive indices.

float fresnelTerm;

fresnelTerm = dot(eyeVector, normalVector);
fresnelTerm = 1 - fresnelTerm*1.3f;

fresnelTerm = fresnelTerm * FresnelAdjust;

//just to be sure that the value is between 0 and 1;
fresnelTerm = fresnelTerm < 0 ? 0 : fresnelTerm;
fresnelTerm = fresnelTerm > 1 ? 1 : fresnelTerm;


// creating the combined color
combinedColor = lerp(WaterColor, ReflectionColor.rgb, fresnelTerm);

combinedColor = lerp(RefractionColor.rgb, combinedColor , alpha);

return combinedColor ;

}
```

I know you have a mine craft style world but I assume you would just apply the shader to each block or each chunk of blocks.

when you come to draw the reflection buffer you will need to clip everything bellow the water or it looks funky also have a play with the cull mode as you may need to flip it.

Clip plain:

```
 dim  reflectionPlane as plain = CreatePlane(120, New SharpDX.Vector3(0, -1, 0), True)
    //Use this float4 on the GPU to clip my geometry when filling the reflection buffer, not sure how to do it in openGL

    dim  planeConvert as vector4 = New SharpDX.Vector4(reflectionPlane.Normal, reflectionPlane.D)

 Public Function CreatePlane(Height As Single, planeNormalDirection As SharpDX.Vector3, clipSide As Boolean) As SharpDX.Plane
    planeNormalDirection.Normalize()
    Dim planeCoeffs As New SharpDX.Vector4(planeNormalDirection, Height)
    If clipSide Then
        planeCoeffs *= -1
    End If
    Dim tempCoeffs As Single() = New Single(3) {}
    tempCoeffs(0) = planeCoeffs.X
    tempCoeffs(1) = planeCoeffs.Y
    tempCoeffs(2) = planeCoeffs.Z
    tempCoeffs(3) = planeCoeffs.W
    Dim finalPlane As New SharpDX.Plane(tempCoeffs)
    Return finalPlane
End Function
```

I also have not tested that shader because I had to pull it out of my messy beast of a water shader but you should get the general idea.

Vertex shader takes World, View, Projection and WaterView as inputs(float4x4).

Pixel shader has two textures Relfection and Refraction, two normal maps for the details on the surface of the water.

Maybe use bigger chunks and some GPU occlusion queries to cull out even more chunks you cant see.

Comment: wow that water looks nice! Do you have a suggestion on how I should store the  data for the water blocks to be rendered because even without any effects it's laggy

Comment: With the water blocks you could get away with drawing only the blocks on the very surface(I bet that's what you do). You could try putting all the water blocks into one buffer and drawing them in one draw call. Walk you octree to find visible blocks then walk your visible block list and put them into one big buffer. I guess for destruction you could have a second smaller buffer that holds the blocks that are within the biggest destruction area you have. Just some thinking, maybe we should turn this into a chat, I'm just not sure how

Comment: I switched to putting lol of the water blocks in one buffer and drawing it all at once. I decided that all of the transparent blocks could be drawn all at once in one buffer after the opaque blocks